# Gradient of Matrix L4 Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I am trying to calculate the gradient of L4 Matrix Norm.

The textbook says that the gradient of  $ f(x,y) = \|XY\|_4^4$ with respect to X is $4(XY)^{\odot 3}Y^T$. But how is this derived?

My attempt:

$$
XY = U \\
dU = Y dX \\
\frac \partial {\partial x} f = \frac d {dx} \|U\|_4^4 *Y
$$

I do not understand how $\frac d {dx} \|U\|_4^4$ can be derived?

Any hints and suggestions are much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: $ f(x,y) = \|XY\|_4^4$???????

Comment: You should add to the problem setup what kind of things $X$ and $Y$ are.  The mention of "gradient" suggests you have in mind a function of more than one variable, but your notation does not make clear what relationship $x$ has with either $X$ or $Y$, and introducing $U = XY$ does not help to clear that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\a{\alpha}\def\b{\beta}\def\g{\gamma}\def\t{\theta}
\def\l{\lambda}\def\s{\sigma}\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\n{\nabla}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$Let's use the symbol $(\odot)$ to denote the elementwise/Hadamard product and a colon (:) to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$

The Frobenius and Hadamard products commute
$$\eqalign{
A:(B\odot C) = (A\odot B):C = \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}C_{ij} \\
}$$
Furthermore, the properties of the underlying trace function allow the
terms in a Frobenius product to be rearranged in several different
but equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:AB &= CB^T:A = A^TC:B \\\\
}$$

---

Let $J$ be the all-ones matrix and define a new matrix variable
$$\eqalign{
A &= XY  \quad&\qiq dA = dX\,Y \\
A &= J\odot A &\quad\big({\rm Hadamard\;identity}\big) \\
}$$
Use the above notation to rewrite your problem, then calculate its differential and identify its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
f &= J:&A^{\odot 4}\\
 &= J:&\LR{A\odot A\odot A\odot A} \\
\\
df &= J:&\big(
         \c{dA}\odot A\odot A\odot A \\
 &&+\ A\odot \c{dA}\odot A\odot A \\
 &&+\ A\odot A\odot \c{dA}\odot A \\
 &&+\ A\odot A\odot A\odot \c{dA}
\big) \\
}$$
$$\eqalign{
 &= J:\LR{4A^{\odot 3}\odot dA} \qquad\qquad \\
 &= \LR{J\odot 4A^{\odot 3}}:dA \\
  &= {4A^{\odot 3}}:\LR{dX\,Y} \\
  &= \LR{4\,A^{\odot 3}\,Y^T}:dX \\
\\
\grad{f}{X}
  &= {4\,A^{\odot 3}\,Y^T} \\
}$$

Comment: Where did you learn this method? Do you have any textbooks that utilize this in detail? Thank you.

Comment: @OneJuan Look for an IEEE article titled "Complex-Valued Matrix Differentiation: Techniques and Key Results" by Are Hjorungnes and David Gesbert.  If you want a more comprehensive source, Hjorungnes has also written a book with roughly the same title.